# How to configure editor in terminal?

Tags: 22.04

I just started using Ubuntu 22.04 and relized that nano is the default editor on the commandline.
I checked with `echo $EDITOR` but there is nothing set.

How do I change it to vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is configured over alternativen system.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

This shows which editor is registered for terminal editor.

you get a screen similiar like mine.

```
There are 5 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/mcedit      25        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    15        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `EDITOR` environment variable, and the `VISUAL` environment variable are usually set in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export EDITOR=$(type -p vim)
export VISUAL=$(type -p vim)
```